# How to copy large data CSV from gmail attachment into google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to get the data out of a CSV report, located in a specific folder from a shared email and replace the old data from a specific tab in Google Sheets with new ones.

I already tried different solutions, but none seems to get me where I want. The code below is the cleanest that I produced but, for some reason, is not doing anything, probably because of the size of the file that needs to be copied, as there can be over 600000 cells of data.

Format: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GyGxSwUtITeje0-Qx63rB8xChMSbLvn1FDCOKOJITio/edit?usp=sharing

I already tried different solutions, but none seems to get me where I want. The code below is the cleanest that I produced but, for some reason, is not doing anything, probably because of the size of the file that needs to be copied.

```
function importCSVFromGmail() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search("label:its {to:sharedemail@company.com} newer_than:1d");
  var message = threads[0].getMessages().pop();

  var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];

  if (attachment != null) {
    var attachName = attachment.getName();

    // Is the attachment a CSV file
    if (attachName.substring(attachName.length-4) === ".csv") {
      var id = "1GyGxSwUtITeje0-Qx63rB8xChMSbLvn1FDCOKOJITio";
      var name = "ALLDATA";
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
      var tab = sheet.getSheetByName(name);
      var tabInfo = sheet.getSheetByName("INFO");
      tabInfo.getRange("B1").setValue(new Date());

      // Clear the content of the sheet
      tab.clearContents().clearFormats();
      var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");
      tab.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
    }
  } 
}
```

When executing the above code, I didn't get any results, nor an error, although it is working perfectly with smaller files. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How about loading the tab in batches using smaller files.

Comment: It will be under a trigger for an overnight update for multiple reports, any idea how to split this into smaller files? (I'm a beginner, It is my first script) Thanks!

Comment: Open up the file.  Get the data as a string and split on end of line delimiters.  Redistribute into multiple indexed files.  Upload them one at a time into a folder where the script can find them and append the data to the spreadsheet.

Comment: Using your shared Spreadsheet, when I download the values of `ALLDATA` as a CSV file and I put the CSV data using your script to the sheet of `ALLDATA` in shared Spreadsheet, no error occurs. And I could confirm the CSV data could be put. Can I ask you about the method for replicating your situation?

Comment: Thanks for your input Tanaike. I know and I wrote in the post that you are not getting any errors, but the data is not pasted into the sheet either.

Comment: @Dan Thank you for replying. When I could replicate your situation, I would like to think of the solution. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: Check if you surpass any of those quota: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas  E.g. maximum attachment size, maximum script runtime, etc. Once you know which limit you are surpassing, it will be easier to think of a solution. Logging (e.g. checking if if condition is fulfilled) and examining the execution transcript helps.